# Trying to create a table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

So im trying to create this table but im getting a #1064 eroor message. Here is my code: CREATE TABLE `JagBank`.`AccountType` ( `typeID` INT(4) NOT NULL , `type` VARCHAR(15) NULL , `interestRate` DOUBLE(4) NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`typeID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

I'm new to php but I was pretty sure this was correct? Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

### for table `jagbank.accounttype`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jagbank.accounttype` (
  `typeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(15) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `interestRate` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`typeID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove size for double data type,
double data type not having size try query below,

```
CREATE TABLE JagBank.AccountType ( typeID INT(4) NOT NULL , type VARCHAR(15)     NULL , interestRate DOUBLE NULL , PRIMARY KEY (typeID)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```